# Issue with memory management and program performance

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

OK, I made a C# winform app, it's a File_Splitter_Joiner.
You just give it a file and it splits it for you to a number of pieces you specify.
The splitting is done in a separate thread.
Everything was working pretty fine until I sliced a 1Gig file!
In the task manager, I saw that my program started consuming 1Gigabyte of memory and my computer almost died! 
not just that, when slicing finished, the consuming didn't change!
(dunno if this means that the garbage collector isn't working, although I'm pretty sure that I lost all references to what was holding the big data chumps, so it should work)
Here's the Splitter constructor (just to give you a better idea):

```
public FileSplitter(string FileToSplitPath, string PiecesFolder, int NumberOfPieces, int PieceSize, SplittingMethod Method)
{
  FileToSplitInfo = new FileInfo(FileToSplitPath);
  this.FileToSplitPath = FileToSplitPath;
  this.PiecesFolder = PiecesFolder;
  this.NumberOfPieces = NumberOfPieces;
  this.PieceSize = PieceSize;
  this.Method = Method;
  SplitterThread = new Thread(Split);
}
```

And here is the method that did the actual splitting:
(I'm still a newbie, so what you're about to see 'may not' be done in the best way ever possible, I'm just learning here)

```
private void Split()
{
  int remainingSize = 0;
  int remainingPos = -1;
  bool isNumberOfPiecesEqualInSize = true;
  int fileSize = (int)FileToSplitInfo.Length; // FileToSplitInfo is a FileInfo object
  if (fileSize % PieceSize != 0)
  {
    remainingSize = fileSize % PieceSize;
    remainingPos = fileSize - remainingSize;
    isNumberOfPiecesEqualInSize = false;
  }
  byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fileSize];
  var _fs = File.Open(FileToSplitPath, FileMode.Open);
  BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(_fs);
  br.Read(fileBytes, 0, fileSize);
  br.Close();
  _fs.Close();

  for (int i = 0, index = 0; i < NumberOfPieces; i++, index += PieceSize)
  {
   var fs = File.Create(PiecesFolder + "\\" + Path.GetFileName(FileToSplitPath) + "." + (i+1).ToString());
   var bw = new BinaryWriter(fs);
   bw.Write(fileBytes, index, PieceSize);
   if(i == NumberOfPieces-1 && !isNumberOfPiecesEqualInSize && Method == SplittingMethod.NumberOfPieces)
   bw.Write(fileBytes, remainingPos, remainingSize);
   bw.Close();
   fs.Close();
  }
 MessageBox.Show("File has been splitted successfully!");
 SplitterThread.Abort();
}
```

Now, instead of reading the bytes of the file via a BinaryReader, I was first reading it via the `File.ReadAllBytes` method, it was working fine with small file sizes, but, I got a **"SystemOutOfMemory"** exception when I dealt with our big guy, dunno why I didn't get that exception when I read the bytes via a BinaryReader.

(that was an in between question)

So, the main question is, how can I load big files (gigs speaking) in a way that doesn't consume so much memory ? I mean, how can I make my program not consume all that memory ?
and how I can I free the used memory after the splitting is done ?
(I actually used

```
bw.Dispose; fs.Dispose;
```

instead of

```
bw.Close(); fs.Close();
```

it was the same.
I know the Q might not make sense, cuz when we load something, it gets in our memory not somewhere else, but, the reason I asked it like that, is cuz I used another Splitting_Joining program (not written by me) just to see that if it had the same problem, I loaded the file, the program consumed about 5Migs of ram, when I started splitting, it used about 10Migs!!
Now that is a VERY big difference .. Probably that app was in C/C++ ..

So to sum up, who sucks ? is it my code, and if so how can I fix it ? or is it C# when it comes to performance ?

Thank you SOOO much for anything you could hook me up with :)

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but the past participle of split is split, not splitted. :)

Answer (score 2):

The following 2 lines will kil you:

```
int fileSize = (int)FileToSplitInfo.Length; // a FileInfo object
...
byte[] fileBytes = new byte[fileSize];
```

1. Your code will fail when the size is over `Int32.MaxValue`.  Unnecessary, just use `long fileSize = FileToSplitInfo.Length;`
2. This corrected code will fail when there is not enough *contiguous* memory. Fragmentation (of the LOH) will bring you down sooner or later.
3. You allocate memory for the entire file but your only need `PieceSize` bytes at a time.

You don't even need to know the fileSize, just

```
byte[] pieceBuffer = new byte[PieceSize];

while (true)
{
    int nBytes = br.Read(pieceBuffer, 0, pieceBuffer.Length);
    if (nBytes == 0) 
       break;

    // write this piece, the length is nBytes 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different aspects that can be made better:

- if you are working with big file, why first read **all** inside an array and *after* write into another file ? Just write into the new file while reading from the other.
- use `using` to gurantee disposal of the streams, in any case: either there is an exception or not.
- if you begin to work with really big file, like 1GB or even more, I would recommend to look on  [Memory Mapped Files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx). So you will laverage incredible memory consuption benefit with some increased performance cost.